# How can I use the datetime library to access the month?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code to help my students login to their accounts if they forget their passwords. This year's school calendar is 2019-2020. If I am a 5th grader I come into the school in 2019. The end of their username uses the year they graduate high school. Therefore my code is adding 8 years from the current year to calculate that number.

However this is the problem, since a school year is split by the new year, if my 5th graders put in 2020, they would get a year thats 1 integer greater.

So how would I specify in my code that IF between January and August you need to subtract 1 from the year, and then come September 2020 the new 5th grade class will use 2020 as their base and therefore they will have the correct digits in their username.

```
import datetime
import sys

def find_info():
  first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[K")

  last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[K")

  grade = input("What grade are you in? ")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[K")

  year = datetime.date.today().year
  #month = datetime.date.today().month
  sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
  #This will only work in September of that year
  #If it passes January 1st of the school year the end number in username will be invalid
  #Need to come up with a way for a range of dates using if statement to ensure correct year

  pin = input("What is your lunch pin / ID number? ")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
  sys.stdout.write("\033[K")

  #if month < :
  #  year -1

  grad_year = -1

  if grade == "5" or grade == str("5th") or grade == str("5TH") or grade == str("5th Grade") or grade == str("5th grade") or grade == str("5th GRADE") or grade == str("5TH GRADE"):
    grad_year = year + 8 
  elif grade == "6" or grade == str("6th") or grade == str("6TH"): 
    grad_year = year + 7
  elif grade == "7" or grade == str("7th") or grade == str("7TH"):
    grad_year = year + 6
  else:
    grad_year = year + 5

  print("Hello there " + first_name+"!") 
  print("\n")
  print("Your username is: " + last_name.lower() + first_name[0].lower() + str(grad_year)[2]+ str(grad_year)[3])
  print("Your password is: " + first_name[0].lower() + last_name[0].lower() + pin + "hoh")
  print("Your Email Address is: " + last_name.lower() + first_name[0].lower() + str(grad_year)[2]+ str(grad_year)[3] + "@learn.hohschools.org")

find_info()
```

Comment: _I cannot figure out how to format the code for stack exchange_ Paste it into the question, select that text, and press ctrl-K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime.date.today().month` returns an integer from 1 to 12, so you can check whether the `month` value is less than or equal to 8 to check if the month is between January and August.

```
  grad_year = 0

  if month <= 8:
    grad_year-= 1

  if grade == "5" or grade == str("5th") or grade == str("5TH"):
    grad_year = year + 8 
  ...
```

Comment: OKay cool, still a bit unsure, if I print the value it returns as the year still when i print(variable) thats attached to the datetime.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you point to exactly what's causing you confusion?

Comment: if month <= 8:
    year - 1

I put this in, outside of any function and what not, in theory that should increment the year DOWN before it is used to add to account for the students grade, however it did not work.